# Animation: Having the camera view move as if someone is holding the camera and running

Tags: animation, camera

In my animation I have a hallway and I want it to appear as if someone is running down the hallway with the blender camera. What is the best way to go about accomplishing this? Should I use a path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two methods you can use to achieve this effect, one of them will produce better results, but the other is easier to set up.

### Match move, with actual footage:

Also know as Camera Tracking. This technique is a favorite of  [*Stu Maschwitz*](http://prolost.com/), ex-[ILM](http://www.ilm.com/) employee and co-founder of the now closed VFX company, the Orphanage. This will produce the most realistic results, but will also be harder work to complete.

**Steps:**

1. Go outside, or into a large room.
2. Place allot of high contrast objects on the ground(a mix of foreground and background markers will yield more precision).
3. Take a video camera, and shoot video like you're the camera man in your virtual scene
4. [Match move it](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-camera-tracking/)
5. Position your camera in your hallway.

This approach will result in very realistic looking results, since it is "Camera [Mocap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_capture)". The down side is, it is a lot of work. As with most visual effects tasks, the more work you put into, the better your scene will look.

### Add random noise to your camera's movement:

This is one of the easiest ways to simulate a shaky camera in Blender. It won't produce as realistic results as the above method, but takes way less work to set up.

**Steps**

1. Add an Empty.
2. Parent your Camera to it.
3. Set a *Location* and *Rotation* key frame on the empty.
4. Open the Graph Editor and hit <kbd>N</kbd>.
5. Add a Noise modifier to the rotation and location of the Camera.
6. Parent the empty to another empty.
7. Use the last empty to control the movement of the Camera.

This can work pretty well, with some tweaking. I would recommend first removing the noise effect from certain axis, if that failed.

> Should I use a path?

I wouldn't bother, just key frame it.