# How to make Realistic Hand-like Camera Movement?

Tags: animation, camera

I am creating an animation, and I want the camera to move with hand-like motion as it does in real life if recorded with hand. Not fixing the camera to one place makes it move with a slow type of vibration.

My question is actually is different I want Motion that occur in real life. I don't just want simple camera shake.
Quick Demo: [Cosmos Laundromat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-rmzh0PI3c)  (Camera Motion Starts after first Scene after 00:48 seconds)

Any Answer Will Be Appreciated.

Comment: imho there is not a single "as in real life" hand-like, camera movement... if you can't use a noise modifier, you should record your "real life" noise perhaps... I'm not an expert but  you could perhaps use the video tracking tools to track a "real life" camera shake and then use that movement for your virtual camera... just trying something...

Comment: see if this helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14671/animation-having-the-camera-view-move-as-if-someone-is-holding-the-camera-and-r (possible duplicate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select camera, hit <kbd>I</kbd> *(Insert Keyframe menu)* and select *LocRot*. Open up the *Graph Editor* window, select each channel and add a *Noise Modifier* ("N" right hand panel, modifiers tab). Play with scale and strength settings.

Comment: @ShehrozKhan if the answer didn't satisfy your question, why did you accept it?

Comment: @SherozKhan the modifier adds movement to the camera. If you play with the settings you can achieve realistic handshake movement.